# How do I use HTML and CSS to get this type of styling in my drop down menu

Tags: html, css

My current drop down looks like this

[image: My dropdown's current style]

How do I use HTML and CSS in a local style to get this type of styling in the attached image  in my drop-down menu

[image: Sample drop down style desired]

See my code below

```css
select:active,
select:hover {
  outline-color: red;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<select id="select">
  <option value="">All Categories</option>
  <option value="Aston Martin">Aston Martin</option>
  <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
  <option value="Bentley">Bentley</option>
  <option value="Genesis">Genesis</option>
  <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="VW">VW</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What you're seeing there simlpy isn't a drop down - it's most liekly a series of divs/spans etc. I would recommend you start developer tools (F12) and have a look.

Comment: You should use the `edit` button to update your question, instead of creating a new one and deleting the old ([How do I use HTML and CSS to get this type of styling in my drop down menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75054378/how-do-i-use-html-and-css-to-get-this-type-of-styling-in-my-drop-down-menu)), this is especially true if the old question already had comments and answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to style HTML `select, option` tags, however, you can you JS libraries, like [this](https://bluzky.github.io/nice-select2/) one. They create the same result, but from other HTML tags, so you can style it as you want. Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-an-html-select-element) question for some more context about your problem.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, standard styling of **select** , **option** tags is not enough. To do this, you need to use third-party tools, such as JS - libraries. There is a cool library - material UI. https://mui.com/

Answer (score 1):

A custom dropdown is a common thing in web development. As Dave stated, the native HTML select doesn't allow styling of option tags. Here is a good resource for custom dropdowns using your own divs with css and jquery: https://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/10/04/custom-drop-down-list-styling/

Comment: Is it possible to get the same result with something else, without jQuery?

Comment: Yes, the jquery here is just used for class selection and adding/removing properties. Most things can be done with vanilla javascript; jquery just does here with less code